# Sencha Touch: Can't add Marker to Map. Please Help?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, mobile, sencha-touch, extjs

I'm having a great time learning Sencha Touch but it seems to me that somethings should be simpler or are buggy. What I'm trying to do right now is **add a Marker to show the current location on a Map**.

I have a Viewport with a top Toolbar and a TabPanel, with a Map on the first card (tab) and I can get the current location without a problem. The problem I'm having is with the creation of the marker indicating where I am.

I've tried event listeners on both the map and it's parent container, but still can't get it to work. Maybe it's a scope problem?! Any help would be much appreciated...

CODE:

```
Ext.setup({
...
onReady: function() {

    var TopBar, Tabs, MapHome, Viewport, Homecard;

    /* 
     *      HOME
     */

    MapHome = new Ext.Map({
        title: 'Map',
        useCurrentLocation: true
    });


    Homecard = new Ext.Panel({
        title: "home",
        iconCls: "home",
        items: [MapHome],
        listeners: {
            activate: function() {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: MapHome.map.center,
                    title : 'testing',
                    map: MapHome.map
                });
            }
        }
    });

    /*
     *      MAIN
     */

    TopBar = new Ext.Toolbar({
        dock: 'top',
        xtype: "toolbar",
        title: "<img class='titleLogo' src='css/images/logo.png' />",
        items: [

            { xtype: 'spacer' },
            {
                iconCls: 'settings9',
                iconMask: true,
                text: 'options'
            }
        ]
    });

    Tabs = new Ext.TabPanel({
        id: 'tabs',
        //fullscreen:true,
        dock: 'bottom',
        flex: 1,
        tabBar: {
            dock: 'bottom',
            layout: {
                pack: 'center'
            }
        },
        items: [ Homecard]
    });

    Viewport = new Ext.Panel({
        fullscreen:true,
        layout:{type:'vbox',align: 'stretch'},
        useLoadMask:true,
        ui:'dark',
        items: [TopBar,Tabs],
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Probably a bit unfair calling something buggy because you haven't got it working ;)

Comment: When you've tried pretty much all you know and remember, you start blaming the system. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event listener for `centerchange` was the best solution I found. And since my map has no interaction whatsoever, that seems to work for me.

Here's the code:

```
Ext.setup({
fullscreen: true,
tabletStartupScreen: 'splash.png',
phoneStartupScreen: 'splash.png',
icon: 'icon.png',
glossOnIcon: true,
onReady: function() {

var refreshMap = function(themap){
// It should clear all markers first, but that is not important right now since the map has all interaction disabled
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: themap.center,
        title : 'testing',
        map: themap
    });
}


    var TopBar, Tabs, MapHome, Viewport, Homecard;

    /* 
     *         HOME
     */

    MapHome = new Ext.Map({
        title: 'Map',
        useCurrentLocation: true,
        listeners: {
            centerchange : function(comp, map){
                refreshMap(map);
            }
       },
        mapOptions : {
            mapTypeControl : false,
            navigationControl : false,
            streetViewControl : false,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
            zoom: 17,
            draggable: false,
            keyboardShortcuts: false,
            scrollwheel: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
       }
    });



    Homecard = new Ext.Panel({
        title: "home",
        iconCls: "home",
        items: [MapHome]
    });

    /*
     *         MAIN
     */

    TopBar = new Ext.Toolbar({
        dock: 'top',
        xtype: "toolbar",
        title: "<img class='titleLogo' src='css/images/logo.png' />",
        items: [

            { xtype: 'spacer' },
            {
                iconCls: 'settings9',
                iconMask: true,
                text: 'options'
            }
        ]
    });

    Tabs = new Ext.TabPanel({
        id: 'tabs',
        //fullscreen:true,
        dock: 'bottom',
        flex: 1,
        tabBar: {
            dock: 'bottom',
            layout: {
                pack: 'center'
            }
        },
        items: [ Homecard, Nearbycard, Waypointscard, Shopcard, Searchcard]
    });


    Viewport = new Ext.Panel({
        fullscreen:true,
        layout:{type:'vbox',align: 'stretch'},
        useLoadMask:true,
        ui:'dark',
        items: [TopBar,Tabs],
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `activate` event is going to be called before your map has had a chance to be rendered to the screen and readied itself. Try triggering your Marker code with the [`maprender`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext.Map) event that is fired by the Map component.

Comment: The problem is still a race-condition between the map loading and your marker code running. Try adding an [Ext.defer call](http://jsfiddle.net/bAsv8/12/) to give the map a chance to load or tie into one of the other events that are known to fire once everything is ready (like `centerchange`)

Comment: I find that the map correctly centers on the current location but the marker that is generated is located somewhere in California (big mansion with a pool!).

I think that `centerchange` event is the way to go. Will post solution.